# Tcl regexp: extraction of all elements

Tags: regex, string, tcl, inline

I have simple strings like below:

```
set x "\ \ a\ b\ \ a\ b\ b\ a\ \ \ "
```

I am trying to extract all occurrences of "a"  and "b" by using the following regexp:

```
set match [regexp -all -inline {(\S+)} $x]
```

But that gives me:

```
a a b b a a b b b b a a
```

I was expecting:

```
a b a b b a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-all -inline` option combination makes `regexp` return a list of all the matches *and capturing submatches* that it finds, and your regular expression includes a capturing submatch that happens to be the same as the entire match.

Try this:

```
set match [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $x]
```

---

If you need non-capturing parentheses, use `(?:…)` instead of `(…)`.

If you have to have capturing groups because you're matching something more complex, you can filter the result with `lmap` (8.6 or later) or `foreach`:

```
set match [lmap {matched ignored} [regexp -all -inline {(\S+)} $x] {
    set matched
}]
```

```
set match {}
foreach {matched ignored} [regexp -all -inline {(\S+)} $x] {
    lappend match $matched
}
```

Note that we're using two iteration variables here and one list, so we pick of elements by twos. Using three iteration variables would pick off by threes, etc. (The `lmap` command is just like `foreach` except it produces a list of the values obtained by evaluating its body script, whereas `foreach` throws those body script results away.)

Comment: Thanks Donal, for a clean explanation.